# How to add ntlm Auth to a post request from UI side through cypress

Tags: authentication, user-interface, automation, cypress

I have my product website when I am navigating through different pages using  cypress it is working fine but website has a key functionality **(Post request getting the payload from some of UI constraints)** which is ntlm secured which is invoked by hitting a button e.g order button

If I am hitting it without using `cypress-ntlm-auth`
I am getting **401 unauthorized**

I tried using cypress-ntlm package but I am not sure how to use it for post request along with payload
This is what I have tried

E.g. only https://reqres.in/api/users

Payload :
{
"name": "morpheus",
"job": "leader"
}

This post request is triggered by hitting **`order button`**

```
Cy.visit(xyz.com)
    cy.ntlm(["https://reqres.in/api/users"], "user1", "pass123")
Cy.get("#order").click()
```

And  invoking the test case using

```
npx cypress-ntlm open
```

But I am getting this error
Invalid host[https://reqres.in/api/users] in ntlmHosts, must be one of:

1. a hostname or FQDN, wildcards accepted.
2. hostname or FQDN with port, wildcards not accepted (localhost:8080 or [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) or *.acme.com are ok,https//www.google.com:443/search)

Can anyone help me on this